# how to fix graphql mutations typename errors

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-client

I try to make a GraphQl mutation using [apollo graphQl client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client).

**This makes an `error 500` when the mutation variables contains `___typename` properties** (which obviously don't exist in the graphQl schema).

To fix that it is possible to set `addTypename: false` in the graphQl client config:

```
const graphqlClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    addTypename: false
  })
})
```

Now the mutation almost works…

But there is a new error: `You're using fragments in your queries, but either don't have the addTypename: true option set in Apollo Client, or you are trying to write a fragment to the store without the __typename. Please turn on the addTypename option and include __typename when writing fragments so that Apollo Client can accurately match fragments.`

**So how should the graphQl client be configured to handle mutations?**

for now I use a cleanup function found [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2160):

```
const removeTypename = (value) => {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    return value;
  } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.map(v => removeTypename(v));
  } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
    const newObj = {};
    Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
      if (key !== '__typename') {
        newObj[key] = removeTypename(value[key]);
      }
    });
    return newObj;
  }
  return value;
};
```

but it feels hacky. Is there something built-in graphql client?

Comment: Are you trying to use the data returned by another query as one of your mutation's variables? Otherwise, it's not clear when the variables passed to a mutation would contain a `__typename` field.

Comment: yes exactly. The `___typename` were added from a previous query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, thanks to @Daniel Rearden idea and [this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1564#issuecomment-357492659) comment, I use a custom apollo link to strip typenames from mutations variables:

```
const omitTypename = (key, value) => {
  return key === '__typename' ? undefined : value
}

const omitTypenameLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  if (operation.variables) {
    operation.variables = JSON.parse(
      JSON.stringify(operation.variables),
      omitTypename
    )
  }
  return forward(operation)
})
```

Then use it with the other links like so:

```
const link = ApolloLink.from([authLink, omitTypenameLink, httpLink])
const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const graphqlClient = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache
})
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach, if there is anything that is not a JS primitive like a File or a Blob, that will be removed (as in cast to the closest stringifiable value like {}) and never be sent as part of the graphQl call, this was the cause of a bad afternoon for me !

Comment: @MatteoHertel I would appreciate it if you could share your method of removing typenames without losing File or Blob data.

Comment: @FaureHu I've added a full version here https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/6#issuecomment-465305186,in case that breaks here's the code
```
function stripTypenames(obj: any, propToDelete: string) {
  for (const property in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[property] === 'object' && !(obj[property] instanceof File)) {
      delete obj.property;
      const newData = stripTypenames(obj[property], propToDelete);
      obj[property] = newData;
    } else {
      if (property === propToDelete) {
        delete obj[property];
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking the value of some query and then plugging it mutation as a variable is an atypical scenario, so there's not an easy solve for what you're trying to do. While you can configure your client instance to omit the `__typename` field from your results, an object's `__typename` (along with its `id` or `_id`) are used as cache keys -- omitting it is going to cause some unexpected behavior if it doesn't outright break things.

By far the best approach to this is just to manipulate the query result before passing it in as a variable. I think something like this should do the trick:

```
function stripTypenames (value) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value.map(stripTypenames)
    } else if (value !== null && typeof(value) === "object") {
      const newObject = {}
      for (const property in value) {
          if (property !== '__typename') {
            newObject[property] = stripTypenames(value[property])
          }
      }
      return newObject
    } else {
      return value
    }
}
```

On a side note, unless you're using client-side data (i.e. `apollo-link-state`) it's hard to image a situation where you would fetch some data from the server and then have to feed that same data into a mutation. If the data exists on the server already, it should be sufficient to pass in an id for it and retrieve it server-side. If you're having to jump through these sort of hoops, it may be an indicator that the API itself needs to change.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. But I don't get how this is an atypical scenario: I fetch an `article` from the server, the user modify some fields from the article and then post back the `article` as a mutation. What is atypical here?

Comment: Conceptually, the type returned by a query and the input type used as an argument are completely different things, even if as Javascript objects they share one or more fields. Just like you can't use types and input types interchangeably within a schema, there shouldn't be an expectation that they can be used interchangeably client-side.

Comment: Come to think of it, you could encapsulate the above logic inside a custom ApolloLink to automatically transform *any* variables you send. That might be the way to go.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the explanation. I would really appreciate an example of the custom apollo link encapsulation.

Comment: oh! and, do you think it's better to remove the `___typename` just after the object is fetched, or is it better to remove them jsut before to send the murtation? (the former sounds cleaner to me)